# Getting Argument Classes of Calling Function "Once Removed"

Tags: r

This is a "computing on the language" question where my skills are modest at best.  I am writing a function to check the classes of the input arguments.  Here is the function:

```
chkArgs <- function() {

    # Get args of the function that called this function
    # stackoverflow.com/q/17256834/633251
    args <- as.list(match.call(definition = sys.function(-1),
        call = sys.call(-1)))[-1]

    print(data.frame(cls = unlist(lapply(args, class)))) # for debugging only

    if (class(eval(args[["x"]])) != "integer")
        stop ("Argument 'x' was not an integer or not found")
    if (class(eval(args[["y"]])) != "integer")
        stop ("Argument 'y' was not an integer or not found")
}
```

This function works as expected, using this test function:

```
testFunc <- function(x = 1L, y = 1L){ chkArgs(); x + y }
```

and these calls:

```
testFunc(1L, 1L)
testFunc(3.0, 1L)
testFunc(x = 8L)
```

Now, if we call `chkArgs` indirectly, or "once removed", as follows:

```
testFunc2 <- function(x = 1L, y = 1L){
    chkArgs()
    testFunc(x, y) # also calls chkArg
}

testFunc2(1L, 1L)
```

We get this output:

```
> testFunc2(1L, 1L)
      cls
x integer
y integer
   cls
x name
y name
Error in eval(args[["x"]]) : object 'x' not found
```

How can I get `chkArgs` to work indirectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve the formal arguments of the parent function `n` steps up the call chain with

```
fargs <- function(n) { mget(names(formals(sys.function(n))), sys.frame(n), inherits=TRUE); }
```

So your `chkArgs` could be written

```
chkArgs <- function() {

    args <- fargs(-2);  # 2 because the helper function fargs is yet another level down

    if (class(args$x) != "integer")
        stop ("Argument 'x' was not an integer or not found")
    if (class(args$y) != "integer")
        stop ("Argument 'y' was not an integer or not found")

    return(args);
}
```

Both cases now check out.

The primary issue as originally written appears to be that the inner check just sees `x` and `y` as symbols because that's what they are in the immediate environment of `eval`. Using `mget` with `inherits` will search up the frames until a value is resolved.

Comment: Thank you!  It works in the toy example I provided, and works in the much more complex actual package.  Much leaner code which is always better.  I put `fargs` in the body of `chkArgs` to keep it compact and it works too.  I'm going to have to study `fargs` to learn a bit more, but I'm able to move forward.  Thanks again.